# Performance/Latency differences - Dynamic vs Static Routes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, routes, latency

If I decide to use a DRY approach and set up my routing dynamically where one route can handle multiple different tasks can this cause latency issues?

This is my first Node.js project and Im using it only as a backend to handle requests using a RESTful architecture, where some data the end user requests can be quite large.

Are there performance differences when deciding between using dynamic vs static routes in node.js. I have around 10 different resources obtainable at there specific route

```
app.get('/resource1', ....
app.get('/resource2', ....
app.get('/resource3', ....
app.get('/resource4', ....
....
```

about half have will pass params or some sort of query. I current it configured for it to be set dynamically then in I have sorting logic then I handle the request like so.

```
app.get('/:resource* ', ....

 [sorting logic for every case]

 [handle request]
```

I'm assuming this will result in higher latency. What are the trade offs and best practice in this case?

Comment: Write your code the clearest and simplest way possible.  The difference between your scenarios is negligible and is not something to optimize for.  If you want to optimize to that level (which there is no reason to do), then give up using any framework and write a native http handler yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the input I also discovered the async module

Comment: I don't see what the async module has to do with route parsing.  Your route parsing would presumably all be synchronous so no point in using the async library for that.

Answer (score 1):

Most route handling logic would take up a tiny amount of time to process that you would not be able to detect.  Regardless, it is best to write it in the way that is most clear, so static routes where they make sense.  Networking latency will affect things much more than a small amount of processing to sort routes.

See the following and useful links off of it for information about performance and latency: https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832

Comment: Thanks this was helpful as I have never done any work in 'real world' and my project is getting reviewed for the first time by someone in the 'real world' and I want them to see it as 'professional' as I may have unknowingly developed some 'unprofessional' habits